# Delete selected Items with modal confirmation in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-4

I have a table where I have Reject button. Once the Reject button is clicked, it open a modal poup for the confirmation. I want that once user confirms the pop up, it should delete the row. But my code is not working. It always shows undefined in the ajax request.

[image: Ui Of the page where Reject button is clicked]
[image: This is the confirmation popup]

Here is my jsp code...

```
      `<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th>User Profile ID</th>         
          <th>Name</th>
         <th>Interested Received On</th>
         <th>Accept</th>
         <th>Reject</th>
         <th>View Profile</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody id="tableList">
  </tbody>

<!-- REJECT MODEL POPUP -->
```

```
  <!-- Modal Header -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal body -->
  <div class="modal-body">
   Are you sure you want to reject this profile? You CAN NOT view this profile in your list anymore if you delete.
  </div>

  <!-- Modal footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">

     <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-ok' id="action"  onclick='rejectRequest(this)' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#rejectModel'>Yes, Reject</button>         
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, Don't Reject</button>
  </div>


</div>
```

`

And this is my jquery

```
function rejectRequest(link){
$('#rejectModel').show();
$('.loader').show ();
var url ="userHome"
var action =$(link).attr('href');
$.ajax({
    url:url,
    type:'Post',
    data:{
        action:action
    },

    success: function(result){
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('#confirm-reject').modal('hide');
        var successUrl = "userHome.jsp"; 
        window.location.href = successUrl;
    },
    error: function(jqxhr) {
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('#action').html("<font color='red'>Something went wrong. Please refresh and try again.</font>");              
        return false;
    }


});
```

}

And once user click Yes, Reject, I want to get this value from in the ajax action var
[image: this is the id which I want to get]

Every time I am gettikng null or undefined value in the ajax request.. please suggest me where I am wrong..

This is the Reject button html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="accept" id="reject_cbd6631d-0c36-4332-8127-094dd5441984" value="Reject=cbd6631d-0c36-4332-8127-094dd5441984" data-href="Reject=cbd6631d-0c36-4332-8127-094dd5441984" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-reject">Reject</button>
```

Thanks in advance, your help is appreciated.

Comment: Change this `var action =$(link).attr('href');` to `var action =$(link).attr('data-href');` and see if it works .

Comment: yes Swati, I tried with this line of code as well but still no any luck....

Comment: Try this -> `var action = $('button[name="accept"]').attr('data-href');`

Comment: This is giving me only first button id but I want to capture the id for whichever Reject button is clicked.

Comment: Use `click` event under  your `function rejectRequest` i.e : `$('button[name="accept"]').on('click' , function(){ var action = $(this).attr('data-href'); //your ajax code });`

Comment: Hi Swati, this is my entire jquery code... I tried your solution but it is not getting inside the var action section, so, it can store the current clicked key... so, I don't know if it is working or not.  function rejectRequest(link){
 var url ="userHome"
  $('button[name="accept"]').on('click' , function(){ 
   var action = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
 $.ajax({
  AJAX CODE  
 })
 });
 
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196678/discussion-between-swati-and-ravi).

Comment: My number is 9891906982, can we discuss over phone, so, I can share you my code and check the possibility of fixing it. If you don't mind...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `function` add a `click` event i.e on click of reject button get the `data-href` value and then open your `modal` and passed value to `ajax` :

```js
$("#confirm-reject").modal('hide');
var url = "userHome";
//on click of reject button
$('button[name="accept"]').on("click", function() {
  //getting current value of button click
  var action = $(this).attr('data-href');
  $("#loader").show();

  //opening modal
  $("#confirm-reject").modal('show');
  //on click of Yes,Reject button
  $("#action").on("click", function() {
    console.log(action);
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'Post',
      data: {
        action: action
      },

      success: function(result) {
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('#confirm-reject').modal('hide');
        var successUrl = "userHome.jsp";
        window.location.href = successUrl;
      },
      error: function(jqxhr) {
        $('.loader').hide();
        $('#action').html("<font color='red'>Something went wrong. Please refresh and try again.</font>");
        return false;
      }
   });

  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form action="../UserHomeController" method="post" id="interestReceivedForm" class="needs-validation box text-secondary">
  <h1 class="margin-top-h1">List of Interest Received</h1>
  <div class="table-responsive" id="table-one">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>User Profile ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Interested Received On</th>
          <th>Accept</th>
          <th>Reject</th>
          <th>View Profile</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody id="tableList">
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="ignorecrossbefore" style="display:none;"> </div>
    <div class="loader" id="loader">
      <img src="../images/loader.gif" />
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- REJECT MODEL POPUP -->
  <div class="modal cstm-model" id="confirm-reject" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure?</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>

        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Are you sure you want to reject this profile? You CAN NOT view this profile in your list anymore if you delete.
        </div>

        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">

          <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-ok' id="action" data-toggle='modal' data-target='#rejectModel'>Yes, Reject</button>

          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">No, Don't Reject</button>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="accept" id="reject_cbd6631d-0c36-4332-8127-094dd5441984" value="Reject=cbd6631d-0c36-4332-8127-094dd5441984" data-href="Reject=cbd6631d-0c36-4332-8127-094dd5441984">Reject</button>
```